# mask for second duplicate elements in a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

given a tensor of integers , how to produce mask of second duplicate element  
Eg :

tensor -> `[13,2,31,46,56,2,53,46 ]` 
I want output of

`[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]`

code implementation in tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
t = [13,2,31,46,56,2,53,46]
list(pd.Series(t).duplicated().astype('int'))
```

result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```